# Calling Windows WebAuthn API in Custom Credential Providers

Tags: webauthn, credential-providers

**Edit1:**

I ended up using [libfido2](https://github.com/Yubico/libfido2) instead. Mind that Windows restricts a normal user from accessing a FIDO2 security token from the HID interface. You should have administrator privilege if you're accessing your FIDO2 security key from libfido2 with the `USE_HIDAPI` configuration, which is the default.

It will <s>not</s>(partially) be a problem for Credential Provider since we will be running in *System* context.

**Edit 2:**

As @Nehluxhes mentioned, using libfido2 **WILL** be a problem for Credential Provider in CREDUI mode.

**Original Question:**

I've made a simple console application that calls Windows WebAuthn API's **WebAuthNAuthenticatorGetAssertion()** which will display **CredentialUIBroker.exe** to authenticate with an external FIDO2 security key.

I'm trying to integrate that application with my Custom Credential Provider by executing it in a child process. However, the UI does not show up on the login page. I went to check the system event log and saw that the authentication process failed with `Error: 0x8000401A. The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password`, which is odd because by using the same credential id and the same security key, the process will be successful in a normal logged in session.

There are some discussions claiming that we could not use Windows WebAuthn API in Credential Provider and that we must use another fido client such as libfido2. However, [one discussion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1052654/fido2s-windows-hellos-webauthns-credentialuibroker?orderBy=Newest) suggests that it was just a UI thread problem and we should be able to show the Broker just like how we create a window in [samplehardwareeventcredentialprovider](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/3e987d98a074051dc9cd5c87431d162035f69a24/Samples/Win7Samples/security/credentialproviders/samplehardwareeventcredentialprovider).

I've tried to call the **WebAuthNAuthenticatorGetAssertion()** using the other thread and also from the `CommandLinkClicked` callback and both attempts failed.

Are we limited to using a third-party fido client in Credential Provider? It will be unfortunate if we could not use Windows WebAuthn API in Credential Provider since it provides a simple way to operate with FIDO-compatible devices.

Comment: this is my problem too. Do you solve it?

Comment: @VOLVO I ended up using libfido2 instead.

Comment: @stevenchucp Note using libfido 2 will still be a problem in Credential Provider CREDUI mode which is running in user context. Though libfido2 have some Windows Hello abstraction that maybe could avoid the problem, but I never tested it.